how to return only ids that dont contain a date
How would I return only ids that do not have a date associated
example:
id    date 
1      1/2/2023
1      null
1      null
2      null
2      null
3      null
3      null
4      3/5/2024
4      6/4/2024
4      null

In the example I would return only ids 2 and 3 since there is no date associated at all with them.
The sql I tried is below however it does not bring back correct information is it will bring back the ID that has both nulls and a date.
SELECT distinct
    f.[ID],
    f.[CID],
    f.[FirstName],
    f.[LastName],
    f.[FA],
    f.[Active],
    f.[Username],
    s.LastEval
    

    into #tempF
    FROM  f
    inner join  s
    on s.ID = f.ID
    inner join  ss
    on ss.ID = s.ID

    where  FirstName is not null 
    and 
    LastName NOT LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z ]%'
    and LastName is not null
    and FA = @fa
    and f.Active = @active
    and ss.T = @t
    
    order by LastName, FirstName



    select Count(CID), 
           ID,
            CID,
            FirstName,
            LastName,
            LastEval
    from #tempF
    where LastEval is  null
    group by 
     ID,
            CID,
            FirstName,
            LastName,
            LastEval

            order by LastName, FirstName
    drop table #tempF


Query doesn't look relevant to the example you gave however you can query with [table].date IS NOT NULL

Try using NOT EXISTS

Your sample data doesn't match your query at all. Is it a 2 column problem, or do you want a bunch of columns? Provide a complete and consistent [mcve].

@jarlh Your query seems correct if the OP only wants the IDs.

@ghostfly What's the expected result?

@TheImpaler, I know, but another approach is probably needed since OP seems to have more columns in mind.

Gyan Institute below answered the question to give me what i am looking for-- i added the other fields in my above query to his to get my results. thanks everyone

Try this for Only Null date Founded IDs:
select id from(
select id,max(isnull(date,'1900-01-01')) from [user_table] group by id
) a where date='1900-01-01'


Do a GROUP BY. Use HAVING to return only id's with 0 dates. (count(date) only counts non-null dates.)
select id
from tablename
group by id
having count(date) = 0

If you want more columns returned, use count() window function where you count non-null dates for each id. Return the rows where this count is 0.
select *
from
(
    select many columns ...,
           count(date) over (partition by id) cnt
    from your-complex-query
) dt
where dt.cnt = 0


if you want to get id only so write query as simple
select Id from tablename where datecolumname is null

